# facebook graph api, enable tagging for custom action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-settings

I'm following the Facebook Android Scrumptious tutorial. In the last step, if I post a meal, it's ok, the confirm action id is shown. However, when I posted a meal with a friend in it, I got this error:

You haven't enabled tagging for this action type (10151609805121984) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard.

The error seems to be very explicit, must be the settings somewhere in the dashboard, but I can't find it. I tried going to "Permissions" section and add "publish_actions" to the field "Users and Friends permission", still didn't work. Am I missing anything? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `App Dashboard > Action Type`, you have to check :

> Tags: Allow users of my app to tag other users for this action.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

One more thing, the permissions should be set with the `login` code, not in the Configuration Permissions settings (which has no effect on the app's actual permissions)

Comment: You just saved my life. I can't understand how did facebook forgot to add this step in their tutorial. Then I remember Mark's statement. Done is better than perfect. they did it but without completion.